# process “mysqld” was terminated because the system is low on memory in wordpress?

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I am getting an error - :

> The process “mysqld” was terminated because the system is low on
>   memory

My hosting provider says that this is might be because of the following type of queries executed -

```
SELECT  wprb_posts.ID
    FROM  wprb_posts
    INNER JOIN  wprb_postmeta ON ( wprb_posts.ID = wprb_postmeta.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  wprb_postmeta as ywmk ON ( wprb_posts.ID = ywmk.post_id )
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( ( wprb_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility'
                      AND  CAST(wprb_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('search',
                               'visible') ) 
           )
      AND  wprb_posts.post_type = 'product'
      AND  ((wprb_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
      AND  ( ywmk.meta_key = '_visibility'
              AND  CAST( ywmk.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('search','visible') 
           )
      AND  ( (wprb_posts.post_title REGEXP 'Global?(.*)Arthroscopes?(.*)Industry?(.*)Report?(.*)2016') )
    GROUP BY  wprb_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  (CASE
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global Arthroscopes Industry Report 2016%' THEN 1
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Arthroscopes%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industry%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Report%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%2016%' THEN 2
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Arthroscopes%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industry%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Report%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%2016%' THEN 3
WHEN wprb_posts.post_content LIKE '%Global Arthroscopes Industry Report 2016%' THEN 4
ELSE 5 END )
    LIMIT  0, 11
```

as well as

```
SELECT  wprb_posts.ID
    FROM  wprb_posts
    INNER JOIN  wprb_postmeta ON ( wprb_posts.ID = wprb_postmeta.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  wprb_postmeta as ywmk ON ( wprb_posts.ID = ywmk.post_id )
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( ( wprb_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility'
                      AND  CAST(wprb_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('search',
                               'visible') ) 
           )
      AND  wprb_posts.post_type = 'product'
      AND  ((wprb_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
      AND  ( ywmk.meta_key = '_visibility'
              AND  CAST( ywmk.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('search','visible') 
           )
      AND  ( (wprb_posts.post_title REGEXP 'Global?(.*)Arthrodesis?(.*)Plates?(.*)Industry?(.*)Report?(.*)2016') )
    GROUP BY  wprb_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  (CASE
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global Arthrodesis Plates Industry Report 2016%' THEN 1
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Arthrodesis%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Plates%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industry%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Report%'
              AND  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%2016%' THEN 2
WHEN wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Global%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Arthrodesis%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Plates%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industry%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%Report%'
              OR  wprb_posts.post_title LIKE '%2016%' THEN 3
WHEN wprb_posts.post_content LIKE '%Global Arthrodesis Plates Industry Report 2016%' THEN 4
ELSE 5 END )
    LIMIT  0, 11
```

Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: explain this query and share the results and also share your tables structure and how much rows you are getting by this query without limit...

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`

Comment: Is an OOM running?  Does the OS have any "swap" allocated?  What OS?

Comment: One question down, 4 to go.